# How to take user input from HTML form to C program

Tags: php, c, exec

I have this small program which takes input from stdin
sample.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int l=0;    
scanf("%d",&l);
printf("\n%d",l);
}
```

ofcourse! compiled it: cc sample.c and got a.out
and i am trying to run it via php like

```
$runcmd = "./a.out > output.txt";
exec($runcmd,$outp); 
print_r($outp);
```

my problem is i dont have any idea how to give input to this program so that scanf can read that?
please help me here!

googling gave some tips like proc_open, popen .... but i couldn't make it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you are wanting to pass an argument into a.out like you would at the command line?

Comment: [`proc_open`](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) seems to be what you want and the documentation page has a pretty nice example.

Comment: I would try `echo input | ./a.out` or `./a.out < input.txt`. Depending on size of input.

Comment: i finally settled with proc_open, thanks for response guys. yet my quest is not over(look at compilr.com they did it seamlessly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at popen
https://www.php.net/popen

it works a bit like fopen, and when using fwrite, insted of writing to a file you can write to a prosses stdin insted.

```
$runcmd = "./a.out > output.txt";
$process_stdin = popen($runcmd, 'w');
fwrite($process_stdin, "text to send to process");
pclose($process_stdin);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you design your C program as a server, you should use sockets or named pipe. That way, you will be able to interact with it without launching it.
You can use popen if you want to use it multiple time almong your script.
If you just need to use it one time, you can just pass parameter as arguments.

Comment: little sample code would be a great help. but good advice though thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not passing it as a command line argument to your C program. Then instead of using scanf you get your input in argv[].

Comment: thanks but the question cant be changed if you dont know the answer :)